# Android converted jar file into eclipse error

Tags: android

i got an error when converted jar file into eclipse.

The error is "Error generating final archive: duplicate entry: classes.dex"

Anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to export a jar to be used with an android app?  If you do that when you do the export you only need to export the "src" directory into the jar.